# Handling chinese characters in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, etl, chinese-locale

Our ETL team is sending us some data with chinese description. When we are loading that data in our SQL Server database, those descriptions are coming up as blank.
We tried changing the column format to nvarchar, but that doesnt help.

Can you please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use the N prefix when dealing with NVARCHAR.

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (N'chinese characters')
```

---

> Prefix a Unicode character string constants with the letter N to
>   signal UCS-2 or UTF-16 input, depending on whether an SC collation is
>   used or not. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the
>   default code page of the database that may not recognize certain
>   characters. Starting with SQL Server 2019 preview, when a UTF-8
>   enabled collation is used, the default code page is capable of storing
>   UNICODE UTF-8 character set.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017